# How to modify template.php in bootstrap theme, to add a class tag to menu li tag?

Tags: theming, routes

I am using Drupal 7 with the [Bootstrap](https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap) theme and a customised [subtheme](https://drupal.org/node/225125).

I would like to modify `template.php` to add a class for each `<li>` in the menu. As per instructions provided in:
https://drupal.org/comment/5830446#comment-5830446

Instructions say:

> "...use this snippet in `template.php` to put a unique id for `<a>` and `<li>` elements at the same time"

```
<?php
/**
* theme_menu_link()
*/
function MYSUBTHEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
//add class for li
   $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['mlid'];
//add class for a
   $variables['element']['#localized_options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['mlid'];
//dvm($variables['element']);
  return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
?>
```

Which `template.php` file should I modify? and how? I have the following `template.php` available:

```
./bootstrapMYSUBTHEME/template.php
./bootstrapMYSUBTHEME/templates/template.php
./bootstrap/template.php
./bootstrap/bootstrap_subtheme/template.php
```

Comment: Bootstrap separated from Twitter some time ago. Just mentioning. By the way, isn't `/bootstrap/bootstrap_subtheme/` an example dir only, to copy-paste to start writing your own subtheme? And where `/bootstrapMYSUBTHEME/templates/template.php` came from? I'm working on a site that uses Bootstrap + it's subtheme (not as an theme guy, but anyway) and we certainly don't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for customized menus used with Drupal Bootstrap subtheme

```
<?php

/**
 * @file template.php
 */

 /**
 * Overrides theme_menu_link().
 */
function bootstrapf24_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables) {
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['mlid'];
    $menu_title_class = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "-", strtolower(strip_tags($variables['element']['#title'])));
    // Another option $menu_title_class = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "-", strtolower(strip_tags($variables['element']['#original_link']['link_title'])));
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $menu_title_class;

    if ($variables['element']['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'user-menu') {
        $variables['element']['#localized_options']['html']= true;
        $variables['element']['#title'] = '<span>'.$variables['element']['#title'].'</span>';
    }   
}
```

without `<php` ending tag.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever in a theming guide you see a reference to template.php without a context, it should (and in official documentation does) mean the template.php in the root directory of a theme / subtheme you are developing.

In your case it means *./bootstrapMYSUBTHEME/template.php*

Never hack your base theme. Your changes will be lost and gone if someone will decide to upgrade it. And if you will upgrade it, you will have to re-write them into new version after each upgrade. Waste of time, subthemes are there exactly to avoid that burden.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The whole content into /bootstrapMYSUBTHEME/template.php